# Removing duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas

If I use the code below, it will keep the column that has NaNs (please see the attached pic). I have other columns that are similar. Is it possible to keep the second one instead of the first one?

```
data_final2 = data_final.loc[:, ~data_final.columns.duplicated()]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Approach 1: drop columns that contain `NaN`

If you only need a fix for this specific case, and you know that your desired column does not have `NaN`s:

```
data_final2 = data_final.dropna(axis=1)
```

#### Approach 2: overwrite column labels with unique names, then pick desired cols

```
data_final.columns = ['Site_nan', 'Site', 'Dimensions_nan', 'Dimensions']
data_final2 = data_final[['Site', 'Dimensions']].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupby` the columns and choose the `first` value, which will ignore Nulls.

```
df.groupby(df.columns, 1).first()
```

#### Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'0': [1,2,3], '1': [np.NaN]*3, '2': [np.NaN]*3, '3': ['1x1', '2x2', '3x3']})
df.columns= ['Size', 'Size', 'Dims', 'Dims']

#   Size  Size Dims Dims
#0     1   NaN  NaN  1x1
#1     2   NaN  NaN  2x2
#2     3   NaN  NaN  3x3


df.groupby(df.columns, 1).first()

#  Dims Size
#0  1x1    1
#1  2x2    2
#2  3x3    3
```